# Module '"typeorm"' has no exported member 'Column', 'PrimaryGeneratedColumn', 'Entity' - Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, typeorm

[image]

When I create the project with the typeorm CLI, It dont recognize the modules and shows in red `'Module '"typeorm"' has no exported member 'Column'`

Answer (score 13):

1. Review if it the module is installed (is must be declared on the package.json and exist the folder node_modules), if is not, install it with `yarn add typeorm` or `npm install typeorm --save`.
2. Review the version of the typeorm, in this example were `"typeorm": "^0.2.32"`.
3. The solution in my case were close and open again the VSCode.

Comment: restarting vs code works for me too

Answer (score 1):

restart ts server will also work.